How to notify a Quarkus application to write to a new file without needing to restart the application
We use Quarkus with quarkus-logging-json extension to manage the logging of our application.
We have voluntarily disabled the rotation of logs by the Quarkus application to delegate it to logrotate Linux system utility which already manages the rotation of logs of our entire platform and our middleware. This also allows not to overload the application when rotating and compressing logs.
logrotate rotates these logs with create and not copytruncate to avoid losing logs (logs are very important for the application, and logs are added every millisecond).
Example of logrotate configuration used:
create 0640 userapp userapp
daily
missingok
maxsize 50M
dateext
dateformat .%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S

Currently, the application continues to add logs to the old file (renamed by logrotate) and not to the new file created (same name as previous, but with new inode).
How to tell the application to write to the new log file without needing to restart the application?
